# How do I speed up the multiprocessing in python

Tags: python, multithreading, multiprocessing

So I had a simple loop in python which after the processing writes data to a `dict`. Something like this

```
for a in alist:
    output = process(a)
    main_dict[a] = output
```

This was working at ~12 iterations per second.

I hoped it would help to use multiprocessing (multithreading) and thus converted the above into the following. Where `process2` gives me the `input, output`:

```
for a, output in pool.imap(process2, alist):
    main_dict[a] = output
```

This is still working at ~12 iterations per second.

I think it has to do with the fact that I am writing the output to a global dictionary. If it is so, how do I make this faster?

Extra info: the function `process` only **accesses** global variables not writes them. I am running this on a Mac with python version 2.7.10

Comment: If you are using multithreading, and your code is not making any use of anything that will release the Global Interpreter Lock as it does work (eg IO, c-extensions) ... then you shouldn't expect a speedup.

Comment: @donkopotamus You mean because I am accessing global variables?

Comment: How do you initialize your pool? What pool are you using? How many elements are there in `alist`? Multiprocessing comes with an overhead cost both for the initialization and for the data exchange ((almost) every piece of data needs to go through a slow pickle/unpickle routine whenever two processes are exchanging data) and with a sufficiently small task that will not offset this overhead you're running a risk of having your code execute even slower than in a single process.

Comment: @zwer there are about 89k elements in alist

Comment: In your second code snippet, `a` is undefined.  So where do you get the dictionary keys?

Comment: If your process(a) is cpu bound you won't see any speedup using threads. You could try timing the process(a) function and dictionary update.

Comment: @PaulCornelius fixed.

Comment: @Marichyasana yes the process is CPU bound :(

Comment: Putting a value in a dictionary is one of the fastest operations you can do.  That can't explain what you are describing.  I suppose that `process` involves an enormous amount of number crunching since it runs only 12 times a second.  Can you describe what it's doing?  Does it access a mass-storage device?  The network?  I don't use a mac, but is there any way you can verify that the CPU usage goes to something near 100% when your program runs?  How many cores does your CPU have?

Comment: @RajVJain - I'm betting that the reason why you don't see a speed up is due to data exchange between the processes. While Mac supports [`forking`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fork_(system_call)) that doesn't mean that it won't have to copy your _global_ data for each process as you have to be very mindful to pull off memory sharing. Sadly, without more info on what your `process2()` does and what kind (and size) of data is being exchanged/accessed between processes we cannot help you further.